# jquery each function and queue

Tags: jquery, queue, each

i have an array:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', ... ]
```

i want it to be:

```
 <div>
  <ul>
    <li>a
    <li>b
    <li>c
    ...
  </ul>
 </div>
```

so i'm trying:

```
$('div').append('<ul>');
$.each(arr, function () {
    $('div').append('<li>' + this);
});
$('div').append('</ul>');
```

but doesn't seem working... how can i queue this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perhaps you want

```
$('div').append('<ul></ul>');
$.each(arr, function () {
    $('ul').append('<li>' + this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of the problem is that you never close the li tags so try

```
$('div').append('<li>' + this + '</li>');
```

For starters...

Something else you can try is the function argument can have the signature

```
function(data, i)
```

Where data is the current element and i is the count.  You might have more success accessing each element that way.  Although, if memory serves, "this" should work in those instances...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div').append('<ul/>);
$.each(arr, function () {
    $('div ul').append('<li>' + this + '</li>');
});
```